# Adding Data to an Object

Tags: javascript, angular

```
targetList: any = [];
public datavalue = [
  {
    value: ""
  }
]

this.httpService.service("Fields").subscribe(
  (
    targetList => {
      this.targetList = targetList;
      console.log(this.targetList);
      for (var i = 0; i < this.targetList.length; i++) {
        if (this.targetList[i].results.multiple == true) {
         this.targetList[i].results.data = this.datavalue;
        }
      }
    }
  ),
  error => { alert(`Can't get Fields.`); }
);

addvalue(i): void {
   var dataObj = {
    value: ""
   };
   this.targetList[i].results.data.push(dataObj);
 }

 removevalue(i, index) {
   this.targetList[i].results.data.splice(index, 1);
  }
```

The data i get In my Service is as following

```
[  
  {  
     "results":{  
       "field1":false,
       "field2":0,
       "multiple":true
     }
  },
  {  
     "results":{  
       "field1":false,
       "field2":0,
       "multiple":true
     }
  },
  {  
     "results":{  
       "field1":false,
       "field2":0,
       "multiple":false
     }
  }
]
```

In This Result if multiple = true then how to add this data .

```
[  
  {  
     "results":{  
       "field1":false,
       "field2":0,
       "multiple":true,
       "data" :[
                  {
                     value : ""
                  }
                ]
     }
  },
  {  
     "results":{  
       "field1":false,
       "field2":0,
       "multiple":true
       "data" :[
                  {
                     value : ""
                  }
                ]
     }
  },
  {  
     "results":{  
       "field1":false,
       "field2":0,
       "multiple":false
     }
  }
]
```

Help in the Adding this format , as the fields are dynamic . I am rendering this into the Html page.

```
                <div *ngIf="targetList.length>0">
                <!-- Index i for List of Elements-->
                <div *ngFor="let target of targetList; let i = index"> 
                  <fieldset>
                    <section>
                      <label class="label">{{target.results.field1}}</label>
                      <div *ngIf="target.results.multiple else singletext" class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-bordered">
                          <tbody>
                            <!-- Index j for Multiple Data within an Element-->
                            <tr *ngFor="let data of target.results.data; let j = index">
                              <td>
                                <label class="input">
                                    <input type="text" name={{target.results.field1+i+j}} ngModel class="input-sm">
                                </label>
                              </td>
                              <td>
                                <label class="input">
                                    <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" (click)="removevalue(i,j)"><i class=" fa fa-remove"></i></a></label>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td colspan="2"><a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" (click)="addvalue(i)">Add Value</a></td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </div>
                      <ng-template #singletext>
                        <label class="input">
                            <input type="text" name={{target.results.feild1+i}} ngModel  class="input-sm">
                        </label>
                      </ng-template>
                      <label class="label">{{ target.results.desc }}</label>
                    </section>
                  </fieldset>
                </div>
              </div>
```

In this one , if i use the above code , it is adding datalist to the second object as well, while i need to add it only for the first object.

Comment: Could you show the service code? Are you using the Observable .map operator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

loop through the your entire json object and look for the `'multiple'` attribute in each of the objects contained within an array

```
 targetList: any = [];

    this.httpService.service("Fields").subscribe(
      (
        targetList => {
          this.targetList = targetList.json();
          console.log(this.targetList);

          for(let i=0 ; i<this.targetList.length ; i++ ){
              if(this.targetList[i].results.multiple){
                 // assuming you have data ready in 'dataValue' object
                 this.targetList[i].results['data'] = Object.assign({}, dataValue); // clone the object before setting it
              }
          }
        }
      ),
      error => { alert(`Can't get Fields.`); }
    );
```

Comment: this will get it added , But i wont be able to add to it again like as following  , for adding again an value to that existing data

Comment: What do you mean by add it again? When you want to add that? You can certainly do that.

Comment: I think reference for the data object are the same. Clone it before you assign. Updated my code.

Comment: i am getting error Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: I just needed to Assign the Object to an Array , This really Helped and saved it.